# Python: getting started with clustering

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis

I am trying to understand what this linkage function in python's hierarchy clustering module does (wasn't able to understand from documentation or other questions that are more complex).

I tried an example with a random vector. I don't know where to begin to figure out what this is doing, why are there 12 numbers in the linkage and what are they?

Thank you

```
dist_vec=np.random.randint(1,10,6)
print dist_vec
[4 2 2 6 5 1]

# create linkage
Z = linkage(dist_vec, method='single')

# distance = 0.8 as cutoff
clusters = fcluster(Z, 0.8, criterion='distance')

print Z
[[ 2.  3.  1.  2.]
[ 0.  4.  2.  3.]
[ 1.  5.  4.  4.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The output format is explained in the scipy documentation.

It's two cluster IDs, height and number of points.

I strongly suggest to begin with 2d euclidean toy data. Not a random distance matrix (which will be inconsistent).